# How to add count labels to stacked graph on R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar, geom-text

So I'm new to R and already checked countless Stack Overflow threads and youtube videos but cant figure out how to do this simple taks. I have a stacked bar graph and wanted to labels on top of each bar for the various values counted.

Here's the basic code:

```
ggplot(data=cyclist_data2) +
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x=member_casual, fill=rideable_type))
```

And the consequent graph:

[image]

I've tried adding a `geom_text` function that I saw in a video but it didn't work:

```
ggplot(data=cyclist_data2, mapping=aes(x=member_casual, y=rideable_type)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity') +
  geom_text(aes(label = rideable_type), vjust = -0.2, colour = black, size = 5)
```

Help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please run `dput(cyclist_data2)` and paste the output into your question so others have a reproducible dataset to troubleshoot your question.

Comment: You could improve your chances of finding help here by adding a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610). Adding a MRE and an example of the desired output (in code form, not tables and pictures) makes it much easier for others to find and test an answer to your question. That way you can help others to help you! P.S. Here is [a good overview on how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is your data

```
df
# A tibble: 6 × 3
  grp   val     frq
  <chr> <chr> <dbl>
1 a     aw       10
2 a     dg        8
3 a     fg        6
4 b     aw        7
5 b     dg       10
6 b     fg        9
```

use `geom_text` to add the labels, `position_stack` gives you the right positions, and `vjust` lets you shift the labels up and down.

```
ggplot(df, aes(grp, frq, fill=val, label=frq)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
  geom_text(position = position_stack(vjust=0.5))
```

Note that you can replace `geom_bar(stat="identity")` with `geom_col()`.

[image: stacked bar plot]

##### Data

```
df <- structure(list(grp = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b"), val = c("aw", 
"dg", "fg", "aw", "dg", "fg"), frq = c(10, 8, 6, 7, 10, 9)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```